# git pull has to be invoked twice - halts after fetch, then performs only merge

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash

I am encountering strange behaviour connected with *git pull* command. It seems that it only performs fetch and halts after that. Second git pull updates my local branch performing merge.

This is the output of commands:

```
$ git co develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by 45 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
 (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.

$  git st
On branch develop
Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by 47 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
 (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git pull
Updating f80464f..61ee4c1
Fast-forward
.../i18n/Views.Account.Login.es.resx               |    2 +-
.../i18n/Views.Account.Login.fr.resx               |    2 +-
.../i18n/Views.Account.Login.id.resx               |    2 +-
...here goes list of files
```

I am using *git bash* on Windows, remote git server is Atlassian's BitBucket.
What could cause this behaviour?

Comment: You can pass `-v` to git pull for verbose output, try that next time.

Comment: try `git pull origin develop` and see still you see the issue

Comment: check exit code of the 1st pull (`echo $?` just after the command in bash). There could be some error which happens to be silent

Comment: @Tom and @max360 that is valid point, currently doing it with every `git pull` I make, however I cannot reproduce this issue - it may have been one time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that the fetch has triggered background garbage collection which could prevent the susequent merge. Try setting `git config gc.autoDetach false` and see if it happens after that.

Comment: That sounds interesting, I've set it and no further complications observed. Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`git co develop`

When you switch from one branch to other branch and already someone pushed something to that branch you see `Your branch is behind` message

`git pull`

this try to pull origin/develop reference, but your branch is not merged with it

you need to merge what you have already pulled by issuing this

`git merge origin/develop`

now changed branch `develop` and `origin/develop` are in sync

Comment: That is not true - see [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) for `git pull` - "Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD."